# How can I join a csv file with a table in hive

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem with a `join` in spark. I have loaded the data from some CSVs and I want to join them to a table in hive.

I've tried to do this based on the documentation but it didn't work

I defined the table as

```
Dataset<Row> table = SparkSession.sql(query);
```

and I want to join it to

```
Dataset<Row> data = SparkSession
    .read()
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", true)
    .option("inferSchema", true)
    .load(path1, path2)
```

I have tried with this

```
data.join(table, data.col("id1").equalTo(table.col("id2")), "left")
```

Comment: And what is the result if you join it this way?

Comment: Can you post `printSchema` from both the datasets?

Answer (score 0):

You should try joinWith

```
data.joinWith(table, data.col("id1").equalTo(table.col("id2"), "left")
```

Ref: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-joins.html

Edit:

instead of left use left_outer, left is not a joinType, and `There is absolutely no difference between LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
data.join(table, data.col("id1").equalTo(table.col("id2")), "left_outer")
```

ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html

```
join

public Dataset<Row> join(Dataset<?> right,
                scala.collection.Seq<String> usingColumns,
                String joinType)
Equi-join with another DataFrame using the given columns.
Different from other join functions, the join columns will only appear once in the output, i.e. similar to SQL's JOIN USING syntax.

Parameters:
right - Right side of the join operation.
usingColumns - Names of the columns to join on. This columns must exist on both sides.
joinType - One of: inner, outer, left_outer, right_outer, leftsemi.
```

Comment: I can't use joinWith because it change type to `Dataset<Tuple2<Row,Row>>` and i need to have type `Dataset<Row>`

Comment: instead of left use joinType - One of: inner, outer, left_outer, right_outer, leftsemi.

ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html

Parameters:
right - Right side of the join operation.
usingColumns - Names of the columns to join on. This columns must exist on both sides.
joinType - One of: inner, outer, left_outer, right_outer, leftsemi.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got an answer. Problem was with schema, when you want to use csv in spark you need to define schema, when you join a table you need to define in schema keys that you've joined even when you don't want to save this field as an output otherwise it won't work

Comment: Can you add the solution in terms of line of codes and accept it